# Powering 3 DC motors (with limit switches) with AC-DC adapter

Tags: power-supply, power, motor, switches, dpdt

I have 3 DC motors: each motor is being used to drive an independent system of pulleys. This system of pulleys spins a threaded bar in order to raise/lower a shelf in a linear motion. Thus, I have a motor and pulley system for each shelf.

The motors are rated at 12 volts each, and draw 4-6 amps each depending on the load put on the shelf. I was thinking about using a 36 volt power supply so that the voltage would split in series, but I'm struggling to find one rated at a safe 8 amps. So now I am thinking I should power each motor independently with a 12v power supply, but this seems inefficient. **My first question is, is there any better way to do this? (I want all the motors to run at the same time when the power source is switched on.)**

I am also using Normally Closed circuit switches so that when a shelf hits the switch, the circuit opens and the power to the motor is cut. (I am using a DPDT switch to swap the polarity so that the shelf can move again - in the opposite direction, until it hits another NC switch.) My problem is, I was thinking of using 2 NC switches for each motor (one on the bottom and one on the top of the shelf system). Although, if I do this, I feel like it could damage the motor: the shelves could stop at slightly different times, so if I was using a 36v power supply and each motor was cut out of the circuit at slightly different times, this means the final motor would be supplied with 36 volts for a brief moment. **So, my second question is: is there a better solution to this?** (I don't want to use one limit switch on either end for the system as the shelves are running independently and could come out of sync over time - this would be especially bad if one doesn't stop in time.)

To summarise: my main issue is with powering all 3 motors from one source, but being able to keep the limit/NC switches independent such that the motors always receive 12 volt each, even if a limit switch is hit.

I hope this made sense - please comment if I missed out on anything. Many thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: I am currently using one DPDT switch to control the whole system, as I wish for the shelves to move at the same time. That's why connecting three 12 volt power supplies wouldn't seem like the best solution to me.

Another edit: My bad, with all the motors in series, it would only take 1 limit switch to break the circuit. This complicates things further; I'm not sure how I would make all the motors function at the same time but have the motors dependent on their own limit switches? If I were to put the motors in parallel, I'd need a 12 volt supply rated at 20 amps?

Comment: If you connect the motors in series to use 36 volts, then the first one to hit a limit switch will stop the whole system (assuming the motors will work at all when connected in series).

Comment: @PeterBennett Ah, I didn't visualise that too well. So I assume the motors would have to be in parallel for the limit switches to work independently on each motor, unless there would be away around this. If not, I'd need a 12 volt power supply capable of handing around 20 amps if the motors are in parallel??

Answer (score 0):

Connecting motors in series probably won't work anyway, because current draw is proportional to torque load so whichever one has the least load will hog the voltage. Also the same power is still required so it won't change the size of power supply required.

Next problem is that though the motors might draw 4-6A each while running, at startup they may try to draw up to 5 times that. Most large power supplies have fold-back current limiting to prevent damage if overloaded or shorted out. So you either need a power supply which can put out ~90A peak, or something else to handle the startup load.

Assuming the shelves will only be moved occasionally, my suggestion is to use a 12V SLA battery, with a 'standby' or 'float' charger to keep it topped up. A 7Ah battery should be large enough. Short circuit current could be well over 100A, so put a fuse in the battery circuit! Fusing each motor would also be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for this. What's the reasoning behind using batteries? When I referred to the shelves moving, I meant in their linear motion, not to another location. Or is this to deal with the inertia current? Sorry if I misinterpreted.

Comment: Also, assuming I still used one power source, and wired the motors in parallel, does this mean the motor drawing the highest current will have the current split across motors? How would I overcome this as this would surely prevent the motor from lifting the load as it wouldn't have the necessary current?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'not to another location', is raising /lowering them not changing the location? Anyway, the only thing that matters is how long the motors are operated for, since the battery won't have enough capacity for continuous operation. The idea of using a battery is that it can supply high current for a short time, without needing a huge and expensive power supply.

Comment: With motors in parallel each motor is free to draw whatever current it wants without affecting the others, because the voltage stays constant (assuming the power supply can handle the total current draw). In series the same current flows through all motors and the voltage drop across each is proportional to its speed, so if one motor goes faster it gets more voltage and reduces current, starving the other motors of power.

Comment: Oh, I see. I currently have a 12v 8 amp power supply to hand. If the 3 motors were in parallel and drawing ~6 amps each, would this be suitable? Is the total current drawn from the motor 18 or 6 amps? From my memories at school I would have thought 6 as current is the same across parallel circuits?

Comment: The total current will be 18A. Can your power supply run 1 motor reliably? If so then you just need 2 more of the same supply. To operate the motors you could then either use a 3 pole switch (with independent contacts for each supply) or gang several switches together mechanically. Alternatively you might be able to turn the power supplies on/off at the mains side, using a single power switch.

Comment: The power supply has been very reliable. Is using 3 power supplies the best way to do this then?

Comment: Or if I found a 12v power supply with the 18A, would this be the same?